# How to reduce the time cost when calling getKieContainer() in Drools?

Tags: drools, kie

I'm using the Drools API to build a kieContainer when my application starts. But I noticed that it cost a lot of time when calling getKieContainer().

I am searching for a method to reduce the time cost to get a reusable KieContainer.

```
KieHelper kieHelper = new KieHelper();
kieHelper.addContent(getContent(), ResourceType.GDST);
KieContainer kieContainer = kieHelper.getKieContainer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it only twice. You're supposed to call this only once when you initialise the application.

Otherwise you can consider using [Drools' executable model](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.59.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#executable-model-con_packaging-deploying)